# MySQL Index Optimization for Microstrategy

Tags: mysql, indexing, microstrategy

I am having some issues getting an index to work for this query (generated by MicroStrategy):

```
SELECT     a11.method  method, sum(a11.call_count) CALLCOUNT
FROM    call_facts     a11
  JOIN    dimension a12 ON (a11.user_id = a12.user_id)
  JOIN service a13 ON (a11.service_id = a13.service_id)
WHERE   (a12.is_fraudulent = 0
  AND a12.is_test_account = 0
  AND a13.in_directory in ('yes')
  AND a11.date > '2011-10-01')
GROUP BY a11.method;
```

I currently have indices on a12.is_fraudulent and a12.is_test_account.  Explain shows an index merge using those two.  a11 and a13 are both good with indices.  What index could I create to speed this query up a bit?

For reference, a12 has about 8 M entries, 7.4 of them match the `is_test_account = 0 and is_fraudulent = 0` cases.

Comment: Why you have a13.in_directory in ('yes') instead of a13.in_directory = 'yes' ?

Comment: The query is generated by some software that my Business Analytics team uses.  I can't modify the query, so I am trying to optimize the indices as much as possible to increase performance.  Right now this query takes about 2 hrs to run.

Comment: I think you need to add index on every part of where. By the way, it's possible to change structure of Microstrategy SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compound indexes usually give better performance than  multiple single-column indexes combined in an [index-merge optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html).

It would be helpful if you would include the current [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) report for the query when you ask for help with a query.

It would also be helpful to post the full DDL ([SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-table.html)) for each table, because "a11 and a13 are both good with indices" is probably not true, and gives us no information about *what* indexes you have defined in these tables.

If I have to make some guess, I would try:

```
ALTER TABLE call_facts ADD INDEX (method, date, call_count);

ALTER TABLE dimension ADD INDEX (user_id, is_fraudulent, is_test_account);

ALTER TABLE service ADD INDEX (service_id, in_directory);
```